# Where I can download for OS X 10.10 SDK for running a Mac Application in Xcode 6.3?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

I have one application related to network . When I am running that application in **Xcode6.3** it is showing like *"**MacNetworkingTesting.app** doesn't have any SDKs to build for My Mac. You can change **MacNetworkingTesting.app**'s Base SDK or Supported Platforms to support My Mac"* and how to run Mac Application in **Xcode**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In XCode select Project -> Target -> Build setting ->Architecture -> Base SDK and select OS X SDKs 10.10. this will remove your missing base SDK issue also.

Answer (score -2):

OS X SDK is included in Xcode. To create Mac App you can go to
Open Xcode -> File ->New -> Project -> OS X -> Application 
And select Cocoa Application Template.
There are many templates available like, for games, extension, Library.